# How do I prevent a database call from hanging in jdbcTemplate.query when the database is not available?

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, bonecp

I am using the Spring JDBC template and a BoneCP Connection Pool. When I purposely set the JDBC URL to an invalid value (to test how my system works on failed database connectivity), it throws an `UnknownHostException` on server start-up, but the server continues to start.  When I submit a request, the `jdbcTemplate.query(sql)` method hangs.  What is a good way to handle this so the system doesn't hang in `jdbcTemplate.query(sql)`?

This scenario is possible if the database is down due to network connectivity issues. I tried to play around with the `idleMaxAgeInSeconds` and `maxConnectionAgeInSeconds` values; I set them both to 10, but the code still hangs in `jdbcTemplate.query()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it seems to me either you don't want the server to start if the exception occurs, or you want to set a static variable that checks if the database is on before trying to contact it (no UnknownHostException when initializing jdbc).

Maybe this points you towards your answer:

http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/

good luck!